# JavaScript нейронные сети не хватает памяти

Tags: javascript, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Написал скрипт, используя библиотеки [отсюда](https://github.com/ssusnic/Machine-Learning-Flappy-Bird)

Нейронная сеть обучается генетическим алгоритмом

Во время обучения видно хорошее движение к желаемому результату

Но памяти хватает только на 11 поколений где-то

Сеть большая, персептрон 200 входов, 60 выходов, два скрытых слоя по 50

После одиннадцатого поколения скрипт останавливается с сообщением на картинке
[image: После 11 поколения]

Если продолжить - естественно, все слетит

Может есть среда какая-нибудь, которая обеспечит выполнение без возникновения такой проблемы?

Перелопачивать все эти библиотеки на другие языки - месяцы уйдут

Comment: где запускается?

Comment: @Grundy в хроме, в консольке))

Comment: тогда прикупи себе памяти в комп ;)

Comment: @Grundy и никаких других альтернатив?)

Comment: Насколько я знаю, у хрома ограничение по памяти для вкладки - 4ГБ. Если у вас ОЗУ больше 4ГБ, то попробуйте запустить на node.js.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Оперативки у меня 8, попробую

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko В Node вроде безотказно, спасибо, уже 17-е поколение, и не собирается вроде останавливаться)